# Grails 3.2.9 custom plugin dependencies

Tags: maven, grails, gradle, grails-3.0

Is it possible to make one custom plugin in Grails 3 dependent on another custom plugin? Here's my project structure:

- grails3-home

  - myApp
  - customPlugin1

    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
  - customPlugin2 ...

I would like to make customPlugin1 dependent on customPlugin2. Everything I've read says this possible with multi-project builds between apps and plugins in Grails 3. And I'm able to declare both plugins as dependencies in myApp with no issues. However, I have not been successful in getting this to work between the two plugins.

I have added the following line to customPlugin1 > settings.gradle

```
include "customPlugin2"
```

And to customPlugin1 > build.gradle

```
grails {
    plugins {
        compile project(':customPlugin2')
    }
}
```

However when I try to build customPlugin1, I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'customPlugin1'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
  >   Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :customPlugin2.

Is anyone aware if what I'm trying to do is possible, and if so, what I might be missing?

**Update:**
If I change my configuration to

```
include "../customPlugin2"
```

and

```
grails {
    plugins {
        compile project(':../customPlugin2')
    }
}
```

the plugin builds successfully, but I am no longer able to import domains classes from customPlugin2 into customPlugin1 domains classes

Answer (score 0):

You should do the include in the root settings.gradle

`include 'myApp', 'customPlugin1', 'customPlugin2'`

Then in plugin 1:

```
grails {
    plugins {
        compile project(':customPlugin2')
    }
}
```

Note that this simply defines a dependency. If you need plugin 2 to load before or after plugin 1 you need to define that as well in the plugin descriptor.